# Upgrade to SQL Server 2016 from SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I have a SQL Server 2012 evaluation in my lab, its license has just expired. I would like to know the possibilities of upgrading to SQL Server 2016.

Can I still upgrade to 2016 and get a 180 days free license with it? Or should I back up the database and restore it to a fresh install of SQL Server 2016?

Comment: I suggest you to ask in Database Administrators. Here just programming questions

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server

Comment: You mention lab - is this for non-production use?  If so, consider using SQL 2016 Developer Edition, which has the same features as Enterprise but is allowed only from development and testing. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/application-development